# How to install new WordPress theme on Ubuntu in XAMPP?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress. I just installed on my Ubuntu with XAMPP on localhost not live server.

My WordPress version is 3.5.1.

Now when I try to install new theme it shows the below message

> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web
>   server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not
>   remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

And prompts for hostname, ftp username and ftp password.

Comment: Just so you know, this is a very searchable problem - I've searched for the exact same thing before, and found plenty of web resources to resolve it. [Search here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=WordPress+needs+to+access+your+web+server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to install the theme over the web or you have a local copy of it?

You can check this link that describes your issue to some extent:

http://www.jasong-designs.com/2012/01/14/ubuntu-linux-permissions-and-a-local-wordpress-install/

and this too:

http://www.chrisabernethy.com/why-wordpress-asks-connection-info/

Comment: I want to install it from web using wordpress admin panel

Comment: Did u check the 2 supplied links?

Comment: @ehp: that second link will help you out - it's a file permissions issue.

Comment: According to second link in my wp-admin/includes/file.php there is no function named get_filesystem_method() . But the link says there is function named get_filesystem_method() .

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Due to linux having such a more restrictive file system, this will enable to you write directly to the folder.

This will solve that ftp problem while installing new plugin or theme.

Answer (score 0):

try using the username: **nobody** and the password: **xampp** or **root** or **toor** or**

> your localhost password [if not blank]

**